# How to check each query executed how many records in JDBC batch execution?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

In JDBC batch Statement added four delete queries so my requirement is calculate row count of each delete query how many records will delete.

Thank you !!!

Comment: Doesn't the query execution return the number of affected rows?

Comment: executeUpdate() returns int which is basically number of affected rows.